# Build number not available to running app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I've got a Liberty Profile app that I am building/deploying with the devops pipeline, and I don't see any mechanism for determining the current build that is running. I've dumped all the environment vars, and nothing appears to indicate the build number.

Is the value someplace I am just not finding or is it really just not available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build and Deploy Jobs in Bluemix DevOps Services offer and environment variable called: BUILD_NUMBER. This variable is not propagated automatically to Bluemix runtimes.

Perhaps in the deploy script, you can add a Cloud Foundry environment variable associated to your app. Something like:

```
cf set-env "${CF_APP}" BUILD_NUMBER "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

so you will have such info accessible from the running code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added the command to my deployment script, and it took. However, there is still no BUILD_NUMBER environment variable in my app. Basically I get the entire env and dump it in a rest call. No BUILD_NUMBER

Comment: @RedBullet can you check that from Bluemix dashboard, going into your app overview, and selecting from left menu Environment Variables, under USER-DEFINED tab you see your BUILD_NUMBER variable? It works for me.

Comment: @RedBullet I did a quick test from Ruby app with "puts ENV['BUILD_NUMBER']" and it worked fine. Of course, I was able to see BUILD_NUMBER from Bluemix dashboard. Can you check if you have there yours?

Comment: @RedBullet using Java you should do something like: System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER");

Comment: Oh wait, I do see the environment variable when I run the cf env command. But it is odd it is not showing up in the dashboard. Probably need bluemix support...

Comment: @RedBullet if you set the environment variable after staging the runtime, you need a restage. Then, in dashboard go to left menu, Environment Variables and then User Defined tab.

Comment: Yea, I know it wasn;t there the first time. But seems good now.